# Taylor Series of ln(x) in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to compute the taylor series of ln(x) for any value of x.

What I have so far is:

```
 clear
 clc
 n = input('Enter number of iiterations (n): ' );
 x = input('enter value of x (x): ');
 y = zeros(1,n);
 for i = 0:n
  y(i+1)=sum + (-1)^(n+1)*(x-1)^n/n;
end
```

But this code seems to be broken and I can't figure out why. Any suggestions on how to improve?

Comment: `sum` is a function in matlab and should not be used as a variable name.

Answer (score 2):

This is a one liner in addition to the for-loop answer provided by @farbiondriven

For `0<x<1` :

```
sumLn = @(x, n)(sum(((-1).^(0:n-1)).*((x-1).^(1:n))./(1:n)));
sumLn(0.5,10)

ans =

   -0.6931

>> log(0.5)

ans =

   -0.6931
```

For `x>0.5` :

```
sumLn = @(x, n)(sum( ((x-1)/x).^(1:n) ./ (1:n) ));
sumLn(2,10)

ans =

    0.6931


log(2) =

    0.6931
```

**Note:** The variable `x` in this formula is bounded as mentioned in this [link](http://math2.org/math/expansion/log.htm).

Comment: That works, after sumLn(0.5,10) does 0.5 represent the ln(x) value and 10 represent the number of iterations?

Comment: Correct. The values substitute in the function as provided.

Comment: It works for 1/2, but when x= 3, there is a huge divergence there?

Comment: The only thing I see is x>1/2, it says the sum can run to infinity?

Comment: That's another formula. The one I implemented is according to your question which is the third one in the table. you can change the formula as you wish.

Comment: ah I see it now. How would you use the sum function to add the second formulation?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
clear
clc

n = input('Enter number of iterations (n): ' );
x = input('enter value of x with abs value < 1 (x): ');
y = zeros(1,n+1);

y(1)=0;

for i = 1:n
    y(i+1)= y(i) + ((-1)^(i+1)*(x-1)^i/i);
end


txt = sprintf('The output is: %f', y(n+1))
```

Comment: That works, but how would you get to display an answer? ftprint?

Comment: @AggrawalPuja the result produced by this code is wrong `log(0.5)=-0.6931` however this code provides `-7.8886e-31` You should check your formula for `ln(x)`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using built-in function and hopefully there is one. `taylor(f,var)` approximates **f** with the Taylor series expansion of f up to the fifth order at the point var = 0.

---

**Specify Expansion Point :**

Find the Taylor series expansions at `x = 1` for these functions. The default expansion point is **0**. To specify a different expansion point, use `'ExpansionPoint'`:

```
syms x
taylor(log(x), x, 'ExpansionPoint', 1)
ans =
x - (x - 1)^2/2 + (x - 1)^3/3 - (x - 1)^4/4 + (x - 1)^5/5 - 1
```

---

**Specify Truncation Order :**

The default truncation order is 6.

```
syms x
f = log(x);
t6 = taylor(f, x);
```

Use `'Order'` to control the truncation order. For example, approximate the same expression up to the orders 8.

```
syms x
taylor(log(x), x, 'ExpansionPoint', 1, 'Order', 8);
```